# Can SKTextureAtlas load bundle from "my" bundle instead of "host" bundle?

Tags: swift3, texturepacker, sktexture, texture-atlas, sktextureatlas

I'm working on a SWIFT3/SpriteKit screensaver and I had the screensaver working except I cannot get my texture to load because when I do the following:

```
// load texture atlas
let textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Flyers")
```

The SKTextureAtlas is looking for the "Flyers" in the main bundle which when running inside of the `screensaverengine.app`, that is not the bundle where the textures live.

In my old obj-c based screensaver, I had to do the following to load images from the bundle:

```
thisBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
fileName=[[NSString alloc ] initWithFormat:@"flyer%d", flyNum];
picturePath = [thisBundle pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"png"];
flyerImage= [[NSImage alloc ] initWithContentsOfFile:picturePath];
```

Before I go the route of loading the images and creating the textures at runtime, I wanted to tap the Stackoverflow family for some help...  thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used SpriteKit.

But looking at the documentation, starting from **iOS 8**, you can use `UIImage(named: imageName, in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)` to get images from any bundle, then easily instantiate your atlas with a dictionary of those images:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
var dictionary = [String:Any]()
["textureName": "imageName"].forEach { textureName, imageName in
    dictionary[textureName] = UIImage(named: imageName, in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
}
let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(dictionary: dictionary)
```